# How to write config.xml to specific application?

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm making a new project using cordova/phonegap.
My application always replace the older though I've changed user in Phonegap.(but it can have one more applications in Android)

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.WYG_V2"
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>WYG_V2</name>

    <description>
        This application is very easy to use.
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="i_am_mind2@hotmail.com">
        CHK 2RJP 
    </author>
</widget>
```

I've learned how to write config.xml by [this](https://beepuengworld.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%94%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%8D%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B2%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B7%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2/)

Answer (score 0):

@Chonkarm,
the URL you gave is not in English. I cannot guess the language, so I can not tell you if it is good or not good.

To fix your problem you need a UNIQUE ID for each App. In your config.xml you need to fix this parameter.

`id          = "com.phonegap.example"`

in this section

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >
```

The section  you need to read is [Phonegap Build - The Basics](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics)

You can get more details from this Blog post - [Builing a release version for build.phonegap.com](https://unbot.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/builing-a-release-version-for-build-phonegap-com/)

Best of Luck

Comment: I've tried but iTunes alert message that "The app already exist"

Comment: You original message said NOTHING about iTunes. You need to check your certificate/profile. It appears to be in error. You also need to read documentation.